# Evento acionando múltiplas vezes quando uso RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-adapter, android-recyclerview

Estou com um problema para trabalhar com `RecyclerView`. Meu `Adapter` possui o seguinte código:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private List<String> list;
    private ViewHolder holder;
    private int codOpe;

    public void updateList(List<String> lista, int codOpe) {
        this.list = lista;
        this.codOpe = codOpe;
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void addItem(int position, String lista) {
        this.list.add(position, lista);
        this.notifyItemInserted(position);
    }

    public void removeItem(int position) {
        this.list.remove(position);
        this.notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }

    public void limparLista() {
        list.clear();
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (list == null) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return list.size();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
        View view;
        if (codOpe != 2) {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.lst_capitulos,viewGroup,false);
            return ViewHolder.vhCapitulo(view);
        } else {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.lst_versiculos,viewGroup,false);
            return ViewHolder.vhVersiculo(view);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
        int inilst;
        int fimlst;
        int intRef;
        int intTot;
        String listaLimpa;
        String desCap;
        String obsCap;
        holder = (ViewHolder) viewHolder;
        if (codOpe == 1) {
            inilst = this.list.get(position).indexOf(")") + 1;
            fimlst = this.list.get(position).length();
            listaLimpa = this.list.get(position).substring(inilst, fimlst);
            intRef = listaLimpa.indexOf("-");
            intTot = listaLimpa.length();
            desCap = listaLimpa.substring(0, intRef);
            obsCap = listaLimpa.substring(intRef + 1, intTot);
            holder.setItemText(desCap, obsCap);
        } else if (codOpe == 2) {
            holder.setItemText(list.get(position));
        } else if (codOpe == 3) {
            inilst = this.list.get(position).indexOf(")") + 1;
            fimlst = this.list.get(position).length();
            listaLimpa = this.list.get(position).substring(inilst, fimlst);
            intRef = listaLimpa.indexOf("-");
            intTot = listaLimpa.length();
            desCap = listaLimpa.substring(0, intRef);
            obsCap = listaLimpa.substring(intRef + 1, intTot);
            holder.setItemText(desCap, obsCap);
        }
    }
}
```

Holder:

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView desCap;
    public TextView obsCap;
    public WebView wbdVer;

    public ViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
    }

    public ViewHolder(View view, TextView desCap, TextView obsCap) {
        super(view);
        this.desCap = desCap;
        this.obsCap = obsCap;
    }

    public ViewHolder(View view, WebView wbdVer) {
        super(view);
        this.wbdVer = wbdVer;
    }

    public static RecyclerView.ViewHolder vhCapitulo(View view) {
        TextView desCap = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_descap);
        TextView obsCap = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_obscap);
        return new ViewHolder(view, desCap, obsCap);
    }

    public static RecyclerView.ViewHolder vhVersiculo(View view) {
        WebView desVer = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.wv_desver);
        return new ViewHolder(view, desVer);
    }

    public void setItemText(String desCap, String obsCap) {
        this.desCap.setText(desCap);
        this.obsCap.setText(obsCap);
    }

    public void setItemText(String desVer) {
        desVer = "<html><body><p align=\"justify\"; style=\"line-height: 1.5\">" + desVer + "</p></body></html>";
        new LongOperation().execute(desVer);
    }

    private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            return params[0];
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            wbdVer.loadData(result, "text/html; charset=utf-8", "utf-8");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        }
    }
}
```

Adicionando o evento de click.

```
rvCapitulo.addOnItemTouchListener(
                        new ItemClickListener(ActInicio.this, new ItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                                String retorno = listCapitulo.get(position);
                                Intent intent = new Intent(ActInicio.this, ActMove.class);
            intent.putExtra(Capitulo.DESCAP, descricaoCapitulo);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
                            }
                        })
                );
```

O problema que estou tendo é que ao reutilizar o recyclerview. Quando populo uma lista, limpo a lista com o método limparLista() presente no adapter, e depois populo novamente com dados diferentes, ao receber o click abre duas telas ActMove.class. Acredito que tenho que remover as views antigas de outra forma ou ainda sempre reutilizar a mesma view mas não achei uma forma que desse certo. Alguém sabe como resolver? Obrigado.

Comment: Onde está a executar o `rvCapitulo.addOnItemTouchListener`?

Comment: Lembre que ele é um *add* (não um *set*), ele regista um *listener* por cada vez que é utilizado.

Comment: Olá @ramaral, o problema era que eu estava adicionando o evento addOnItemTouchListener mais de uma vez. Seu comentário me ajudou a ver isso. Muito obrigado.